# Impossible to remove a variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables

I have come across the strangest behaviour that has been driving me nuts when writing scripts. It is impossible sometimes to remove the value of a variable in Powershell. I have tried:

```
Remove-Variable -Force
```

Also tried making it equal to an empty string or making it `$null` but the variable value and type remains.

Anyone have an idea how this can happen?

I am using Powershell version 5 on Windows Server 2016.

Here some screenshots:

[image: Null]
[image: Remove Variable]

Comment: Cannot reproduce this behavior, please add all necessary lines to reproduce this. And please insert code directly instead of images of code.

Comment: Have you tried `Remove-Variable  -Name "date"`?

Comment: PLEASE, do not show images of code/errors/data. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: The only explanation for the first screenshot I can think of is: You initially type-constrained `$date` to `[datetime]` - e.g. `[datetime] $date = Get-Date` - and `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` is in effect (which is not good idea, except temporarily); only then would `$date = $null` _fail silently_ while retaining its existing value. The conceptual problem with your second screenshot is explained in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**To remove a variable, pass its *name* *without the `$` sigil* to the [`Remove-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/remove-variable) cmdlet's

`-Name` parameter** (which is positionally implied); using the example of a variable `$date`:

- Using an *argument*:

```sh
# Note the required absence of $ in the name; quoting the var. name is
# optional in this case.
Remove-Variable -Force -Name date
```

- Using the *pipeline* would require you to specify *objects* whose `.Name` property contains the name of the variable to delete, because these property values implicitly bind to `Remove-Variable`'s `-Name` parameter; the simplest way to achieve that is to use the [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) cmdlet, which too requires specifying the name without the `$`:

```sh
# Works, but is inefficient.
Get-Variable -Name date | Remove-Variable -Force
```

However, this is both more verbose and less efficient than directly passing the name(s) as an *argument*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

You variable-removal command is conceptually flawed:

> `$date | Remove-Variable -Force`

**Except as the LHS of an *assignment* (`$date = ...`), referring to a variable with the `$` sigil returns its *value*, not the *variable itself*.**

That is, since your `$date` variable contains a `[datetime]` instance, it is that instance that is sent through the pipeline, and since only *strings* are supported as input - that is, variable *names* - the command fails.

In effect, your call is equivalent to the following, which predictably fails:

```sh
PS> Get-Date | Remove-Variable -Force
Remove-Variable : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command 
either because the command does not take pipeline input 
or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
```

What the somewhat verbose, general error message is implying in this case is that the input object was of the wrong type (because only objects with a `.Name` property are accepted, which `[datetime]` doesn't have).

---

**Contexts in which you need refer to a *variable itself* rather than to *its value*:**

What these contexts have in common is that **you need to specify the variable name *without the `$` sigil***.

Two notable examples:

- All `*-Variable` cmdlets expect the *names* of variables to operate on, such as the [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) cmdlet that returns *objects representing variables*, of type [`System.Management.Automation.PSVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSVariable); these objects include the name, value, and other attributes of a PowerShell variable.

  ```
  # Gets an object describing variable $date
  $varObject = Get-Variable date  # -Name parameter implied
  ```
- When you pass the name of an output variable to a `-*Variable` [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters)

  ```
  # Prints Get-Date's output while also capturing the output 
  # in variable $date.
  Get-Date -OutVariable date
  ```

As implied, above, ***assigning* to a variable with `=` is the only exception: there you *do* use the `$` sigil**, e.g. `$date = Get-Date`.

Note that this **differs from POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`**, where you do *not* use `$` in assignments (and must not have whitespace around `=`); e.g., `date=$(date)`.